# Cross Building From Mac (OS X Capitan) For Raspberry Pi3 (Jessie)

Tags: c++, linux, macos

I'm failing to compile a database on my pi therefore I want to compile it on my mac.

I follow mostly this [tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/User:Max/Building_a_GCC_4.9_cross_compiler_on_OS_X_Mavericks) to build my cross compiler.

## System

### Mac

My Mac is running with `OS X El Capitan 10.11.3` 
`uname -a` gives me:
`Darwin Andreass-MacBook-Air-2.local 15.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

### Pi

`uname -a`:
`Linux raspberrypi 4.1.14-v7+ #4 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 23 15:30:13 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux`
Running `./configure --with-system-malloc --allow-fetch` in the folder of the db I want to install, gives me the additional info:

`* Detecting system configuration
Bash:                           4.3.30(1)-release
Use ccache:                     no
C++ Compiler:                   GCC 4.9.2 (/usr/bin/c++)
Host System:                    arm-linux-gnueabihf
Build System:                   Linux 4.1.14-v7+ armv7l
Cross-compiling:                no
Host Operating System:          Linux
Build Architecture:             armv7l
C++11:                          ok
Precompiled web assets:         yes
Protobuf compiler:              /usr/bin/protoc
python:                         python 2.7.9
Node.js package manager:        /usr/local/bin/npm
coffee:                         external/coffee-script_1.10.0
Browserify:                     external/browserify_12.0.1
bluebird:                       external/bluebird_2.9.32
web UI dependencies:            external/admin-deps_2.0.3
wget:                           /usr/bin/wget
curl:                           /usr/bin/curl
Google Test:                    external/gtest_1.7.0
termcap:                        no
boost_system:                   external/boost_1.56.0
protobuf:                       -lprotobuf
v8 javascript engine:           external/v8_3.30.33.16
RE2:                            external/re2_20140111
z:                              -lz
crypto:                         external/openssl_1.0.1i
ssl:                            external/openssl_1.0.1i
curl:                           external/curl_7.40.0
malloc:                         system
Test protobuf:                  ok
Test boost:                     external/boost_1.56.0
Test OpenSSL:                   external/openssl_1.0.1i
Installation prefix:            /usr/local
Configuration prefix:           /usr/local/etc
Runtime data prefix:            /usr/local/var`

### Compiler Setup

I installed all the required packages from the tutorial and downloaded
- `binutils-2.26.51`
- `gcc-5.3.0`

I set the export variables as following:

```
export CC=gcc-4.9
export CXX=g++-4.9
export CPP=cpp-4.9
export LD=gcc-4.9

export PREFIX="$HOME/opt/cross"
export TARGET="Linux 4.1.14-v7+"
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"
```

## Error

```
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `4.1.14-v7+': machine `4.1.14' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ../binutils-2.26.51/config.sub 4.1.14-v7+ failed
```

Before I had this error, there was also the requirement to specify a host.

### Questions

1) What to specifiy for the target?

2) What else needs to be adjusted, from the tutorial, to get it working?

EDIT:
As suggested is the target on the cross compiling machine the target machine: `arm-linux-gnueabihf`

I guess `./bfd` is from this folder `/Users/MasterG/opt/cross` => `/Users/MasterG/opt/cross/bfd` which does not exist, because the whole folder did not exist before.

Comment: Target should probably be 'arm-linux-gnueabihf' (the 'host system' line in your output). You should probably use the same as the GCC that's included in Raspbian, which you can get by running `gcc -v` on the Pi.

Comment: The tutorial also doesn't cover importing the headers and C library from your Pi into the build tree: the configure line has `--without-headers` which, IIRC, means you're building a 'bare metal' cross-compiler without a target OS. You probably want to copy over /usr/include and some or all of /usr/lib from your Pi to somewhere you can access it on your mac and then pass the paths to GCC's configure using `--with-headers` etc. I haven't done this in years so I can't be more specific sorry.

Comment: Thx, the target works. For the headers I will read into this. Do you have any idea about the missing folder (see edit). Does bare metal mean, that it will not work on the target OS (I thought that was the main sense of building the compiler, to get it working on a diff system).

Comment: Here's [another tutorial](http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/cross-compiling-on-mac-osx-for-raspberry-pi/) which looks like it's getting headers and libraries by compiling eglibc instead. However [raspbian jessie] appears to [use glibc instead](https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie/glibc), so I don't think that's right for you, and you'll almost certainly need some kernel headers too - so probably easiest to copy from the Pi.

Comment: BFD should be part of binutils: I'd guess that should be a 'bfd' folder that's missing under 'buildfolder', not opt/cross. Did it build bfd? If `make install` isn't building anything you might need to just `make` first.

Comment: [arm-cross-compiling-with-mac-os-x](http://www.welzels.de/blog/en/arm-cross-compiling-with-mac-os-x/)

Comment: There failed something. I restarted everything and now it went fine. I will read through the tutorials and report here + provide a tutorial if I'm successful. Thanks a lot!